# LESS and SASS source code formatting

Tags: highlighting, syntax, sourcecode

I need to add piece of source code in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Piece of code is divided into two columns. First column is source code in Less and second column in Sass, something like on [this](https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/674726) page, but without borders.

I know about verbatim, but I would like to know if there is something better to save more space (because of two columns) and LESS and SASS syntax highlighting (I dont need color, bold and italic is enough).

Comment: Interesting question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want automatic syntax highlighting, I'd suggest you to use either  [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted). Below I present two options using the former.

Here's a first option; the idea is to the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and two side-by-side `minipage`s; two environments `sass` and `less` are defined using `\lstnewenvironment`; since the languages are not predefined, I gave a simple dummy definition for the example:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bera}

% Definitions for the SASS language
\lstdefinelanguage{sass}
{
  morekeywords={border,solid},
}

% Definitions for the LESS language
\lstdefinelanguage{less}
{
  morekeywords={bordered,black},
}

% Common settings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries
}

% Definition of the main environments
\lstnewenvironment{sass}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=sass,linewidth=\linewidth,#1}}
  {}
% Definition of the main environments
\lstnewenvironment{less}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=less,linewidth=\linewidth,#1}}
  {}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{sass}
  {\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}SASS}
\AfterEndEnvironment{sass}{\end{minipage}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{less}
  {\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}LESS}
\AfterEndEnvironment{less}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sass}
.bordered(@width: 2px) {
  border: @width solid black;
} 
#menu a {
  .bordered(4px);
}
\end{sass}%
\begin{less}
@mixin bordered($width: 2px) {
  border: $width solid black;
}
#menu a {
  @include bordered(4px);
}
\end{less}

\end{document}
```

Here's another option using the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and its interaction with [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{bera}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

% Definitions for the SASS language
\lstdefinelanguage{sass}
{
  morekeywords={border},
}

% Definitions for the LESS language
\lstdefinelanguage{less}
{
  morekeywords={bordered},
}

% Common settings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries
}

% Just a snippet of LESS code for the example
\begin{filecontents*}{lessi.cd}
@mixin bordered($width: 2px) {
  border: $width solid black;
}                                 | }
#menu a {
  @include bordered(4px);
}
\end{filecontents*}

% Definition of the main environment
\newtcblisting{lesssass}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  top=10pt,
  listing options={language=sass},
  colback=gray!5,
  colframe=gray,
  listing side comment,
  comment={#2},
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west,inner ysep=4pt] at (frame.north west) (sa) {SASS};
    \node[anchor=north west,inner ysep=4pt] at (frame.north) (le) {LESS};
    \draw[gray,line width=0.5pt] 
      (frame.north west|-sa.south) --  (frame.north east|-sa.south);
  },
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lesssass}{\lstinputlisting[language=less]{lessi.cd}}
.bordered(@width: 2px) {
  border: @width solid black;
} 
#menu a {
  .bordered(4px);
}
\end{lesssass}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- Since LESS and SASS are not predefined languages in `listings`, you'll need to provide the language definitions using `\lstdefinelanguage`; in my example code I used to simple definitions just for the example:

  ```
  % Definitions for the SASS language
  \lstdefinelanguage{sass}
  {
    morekeywords={border},
  }

  % Definitions for the LESS language
  \lstdefinelanguage{less}
  {
    morekeywords={bordered},
  }
  ```
- In my solution, the SASS code is typeset directly in your document, inside the main environment; the LESS code has to be stored in an external file (which I simulated in my example using `filecontents`) and will be input using `\lstinputlistings` (see the example code).
- The main environment is `lesssass`; the content of the environment is the SASS code (which will be typeset to the left of the box); using the mandatory argument and `\lstinputlistings`, you can write the LESS code (to be typeset to the right of the box). For example, the document was produced using

  ```
  \begin{lesssass}{\lstinputlisting[language=less]{lessi.cd}}
  .bordered(@width: 2px) {
    border: @width solid black;
  } 
  #menu a {
    .bordered(4px);
  }
  \end{lesssass}
  ```

  using the following file `lessi.cd`:

  ```
  @mixin bordered($width: 2px) {
    border: $width solid black;
  }                                 | }
  #menu a {
    @include bordered(4px);
  }
  ```